# Continuous RV: PDF/CDF (Geometric)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, geometric-probability

Let vector $(X, Y)$ be distributed uniformly on a support of triangular shape $ABC$, where $A=(0;0), B=(2;0), C=(1,1)$. Find $PDF$ and $CDF$ of random variables $X$ and $Y$. Are those random variables independent?

Could you help me with this one? I do have some experience with the basic geometric probability, however I literally don't know what and how to apply here..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When they say $Z \sim U(\Omega), \Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, this means that the PDF is the same in every point, if it is in the support $\Omega$ and zero otherwise:

$$ p(z) = \begin{cases}C, \text{ if } z \in \Omega \\ 0, \text{ if } z \notin \Omega \end{cases} $$,

where the constant C is chosen so that $\int_\Omega C \mathrm{d} z = 1$.

In your case $n = 2$, $z = (x,y)$ and $\Omega = \Delta ABC$.

For the integration purposes the support of $(X,Y)$ can be expressed as the following constraint on values of $Y$:

$$ 
\Delta ABC = \left\{(x,y) \in [0,2] \times \mathbf{R} \bigg| \begin{cases} y \in (0,x) &\text{ if } x \in [0,1],\\ y \in (0,2-x) &\text{ if } x \in (1,2] \end{cases}\right\}.
$$

So

$$ C = \left(\int_{\Delta ABC} 1 \mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}x\right)^{-1} = \frac{1}{S_{\Delta ABC}} = 1,$$

therefore

$$ p(x,y) = 1 \text{ if } (x,y) \in \Delta ABC, \text{ and } 0 \text{ otherwise}.$$

To obtain PDF of $X$ in a certain point $X=x$, you must integrate the joint PDF over all values of $Y$ that are consistent with $x$:

$$ p(x) = \begin{cases} \int_0^x 1 \mathrm{d} y = x, \text{ if } x\in [0,1], \\ 
           \int_0^{2-x} 1 \mathrm{d} y = 2 - x, \text{ if } x \in (1,2],\\
0 \text{ otherwise}.
    \end{cases} $$

The CDF is computed from the PDF according to the definition:

$$ P(x) = \int_0^x p(\xi) \mathrm{d} \xi = \begin{cases} 0, \text{ if } x < 0, \\ \frac{x^2}{2}, \text{ if } x \in [0,1], \\ 2x - \frac{x^2}{2}, \text{ if } x \in (1,2], \\ 1, \text{ if } x > 2.   \end{cases}$$

By the same token, you can easily find the PDF and CDF of $Y$.

Comment: Got the same for X, will check what is with Y now, thanks a lot! I was not sure whether my solution flows the right path, now I see :)

Comment: Sure, no problem. Please upvote the the answer as well, it did take a bit of time to write it up.

Comment: However, looks like something odd is happening with $p(x)$ integral limits..

Comment: You should be more specific, if you want explanations.

Comment: Not really get it, why for $x \in (1,2]$ we integrate from 0 to (2-x), may you add some details with indicators manipulating, please?

Comment: The thing is, I was told to try avoiding geometry here, so I've used following technique: $\rho_X(a)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} Ind(y<a, y<(2-a), y>0)dy$ from that point of view your sectioning $[0,1]; (1;2], etc$ is not that straightforward, unfortunately

Comment: $Ind(y<a,y<2-a) = Ind(y<a)$ if $a < 1$ and  $Ind(y<2-a)$ if $a >1$. Then you have to get rid of $Ind$'s and adjust the integration boundaries.

Comment: Got it, thanks again!